# Why is there an extra nill output in Rails?- loop in partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

The problem is in my view i have one extra nill output generated by AtionCable!
I have reset the database but it didnt help.Even when there is no record in database you can see this nill output.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4hd1.png)

```
<div id="allcomments">
  <%= render partial: 'hot/post_comments', locals: {allcomment: @allcomments}%>
</div>
```

In partial:

```
<% allcomment.each do |s|   %>
  <%= s %>
  <div class="well">
    <%= s.comment %>
  </div>  
<% end %>
```

channel.coffee:

```
received: (data) ->
  $('#allcomments').append data['commentpost']
```

[image][image]

In my controller :

```
@allcomments = @thispost.commentposts
```

Comment: i disabled ActionCable and still same problem. so it shouldnt be from action cable

Comment: What is `@thispost`?

Comment: @Pavan You are right. Thank you for your help, i found a solution. if you can explain it why please copy my answer and right your explanation for the reason of it and i will mark your answer. i will edited my question a bit for people with same issue to save their time. "@thispost" is the post which people can comment under it

Comment: I mean show me the code for `@thispost`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: I don't know why but in controller I had this line:

```
@allcomments = @thispost.commentposts
```

Which returned one extra `nil` record which is not saved in database as well so you can not do something like `<% @user= Users.find(f.user_id) %>` in your view because it will give you the error `can not find User with nill id`.

That's because loop view contained one extra output which is `nil`.

so solution for me was this in controller :

```
@allcomments = Commentpost.where(post_id: @thispost.id )
```

If someone know why my first comment returns an extra `nil` output please let me know, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's just returning the evaluation of the .each, which is nil when you have no records, and then appending that to the html. So you need to either account for when you have no records, and return an appropriate html for that, or on the js/coffee

You could add a check on the partial

```
<%- if !allcomment.blank? -%>
    do what you already have
<%- else %->
    <div class="no_results">No comments</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I have tried your solution, still same result! <% allcomment.each do |s|   %>

<% if !s.blank? %>

  
<div class="well ">
<%= s.comment %>
 </div> 

<% else %>
    <div class="no_results">No comments</div>
<% end %>


<% end %>